# CSS :target pseudo class and sibling issue

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm attempting to change the properties of a div when a different div has been :target(ed). A JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/FC5sQ/. The line where (I believe) the issue stems from is the

```
#tevents:target ~ .titlewrap {top:0;}
```

line in the CSS. Basically, once the #tevents id is targeted, I want the titlewrap class to have a top value of 0.

Comment: `:target` is a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element or pseudo-selector.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the :target pseudo class can't be used like that.

Comment: @j08691: `:target` can be used with any combinators. The issue here lies in the combinator and not `:target`, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general sibling combinator `~` doesn't work backwards. So, since your `.titlewrap` is coming before `#tevents` in your HTML, your selector won't work.

Unfortunately [there's no previous sibling combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector), so if you can't change the markup and style the changes accordingly, then you can't do this with `:target` and a sibling combinator.

By the way, your `top: 30%` style isn't taking any effect either, and that's because you didn't set an explicit `height` for your `.titlewrap`.

Comment: If that's the case, would a modified HTML structure with the #tevents div defined before the .titlewrap div work? I tried it in JSFiddle, and the result was the same as before.

Comment: @natosennimi: It will work, I explain in the last paragraph why your result is the same. You need to define a height for your `.titlewrap`.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out. BTW, the `top:30%;` on the `.titlewrap` works/shows up just fine on my browser. Maybe a x-browser compatibility issue.